# Jetpack Compose recomposition animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-jetpack-compose

Is there any easy way to animate Composables appearing/hiding?
I tried to implement this using AnimatedVisibility and AnimatedContent, but in my particular case it looked rather cumbersome.
The content on the screen is dynamic and depends on the value of the variable, when changing this variable I need to show / hide the corresponding Composables with animation.

```
contentType.forEach { type ->
                when (type) {
                    ContentType.Type1 -> {
                        ComposableForType1()
                    }
                    ContentType.Type2 -> {
                        ComposableForType2()
                    }
                    ContentType.Type3 -> {
                        ComposableForType3()
                    }
                    ContentType.Type4 -> {
                        ComposableForType4()
                    }
                }
}
// Some logic to change the content type
```

Comment: `AnimatedVisibility` is the right way, add code of how you use it, and also describe what you expect and what doesn't work correctly

Comment: @PhilipDukhov, I don't fully understand what to do with the "Visible" variable, as it controls the visibility of all content. Here's the [code](https://codeshare.io/eVKNyK)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `AnimatedVisibility` to show/hide one specific view.

In the case where you want to animate some state between different views, you can use the [`Crossfade`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation#crossfade) animation:

```
Crossfade(targetState = type) { type ->
    when (type) {
        ContentType.Type1 -> {
            ComposableForType1()
        }
        ContentType.Type2 -> {
            ComposableForType2()
        }
        ContentType.Type3 -> {
            ComposableForType3()
        }
        ContentType.Type4 -> {
            ComposableForType4()
        }
    }
}
```

This method will definitely work if in case when `type` is a normal mutable value.

I'm not sure it will work in your case, because you also have an array of data. If you only change the value in the array, `Crossade` will work, but if you also add or delete an element, this animation will be harder to implement.

Check out more about Compose animations in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation)

Comment: Overall, I managed to implement animation. But it's a shame that I had to limit myself to the "crossfade" animation. I managed to trace the nested value of a variable, I don't know how elegant it is, but [it](https://codeshare.io/eVKNyK) works

Comment: @TimYumalin you can specify `animationSpec` if the visual part is not what you're looking for